# Method of expressing the product of first n integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

I am trying to show a pattern whereby the first term is *140* the next term is $140\times139$ and the next $140\times139\times138\dots$
I can do this as follows:

$\frac{140!}{(140-n)!}$ but that doesnt hold for negative numbers i.e. $140\times139\dots\times-1\times\dots$

How can I do this?

Comment: With negative numbers, you pass by $0$, so it's $0$.

Comment: ah silly me, thanks, for some reason I figured it wouldnt end up being zero!

Comment: Sorry, been slacking on the accepting of answers, will get back in the habbit haha! thanks for the friendly reminder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$f(n):=\begin{cases}\tfrac{140!}{(140-n)!}&\text{if }1\le n\le 140,\\
0&\text{if }n>140.\end{cases} $$

Answer (score 1):

Just use Knuth's notation for *falling factorial powers*:
$$
x^{\underline{k}} = x (x - 1) (x - 2) \ldots (x - k + 1)
$$
I.e., $k$ factors, decreasing by 1 each. This is a polynomial of degree $k$ in $x$.

Similarly, *raising factorial powers*:
$$
x^{\overline{k}} = x (x + 1) (x + 2) \ldots (x + k - 1)
$$

There are several notations around for those, like $(x)_k$.